# Inverse Laplace transform of the form $F(s) = \frac{s^{m}}{(1+a \cdot s)^{n}(1+b \cdot s)^{h}}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to solve the inverse Laplace transform of the form
\begin{equation}
F(s) = \frac{s^{m}}{(1+a \cdot s)^{n}(1+b \cdot s)^{h}}
\end{equation}
where, $a$ and $b$ are known constants, $m$, $n$, and $h$ are all positive integers.

If $n$ and $h$ is known, then we might use the residue theorem to get the answer. However, in the case of this problem, $n$ and $h$ are unknown, which means that the higher order derivatives used for the residue theorem might be difficult to get.

Do you have any ideas on solving this problem. Thanks a lot in advane.

Comment: If you do not know all of your data, then how on earth do you propose to compute the inverse?

Comment: Hi, here we assume that $a, b$ are known, and $m, n, h$ are known variables as well. So I want to known whether there is a unified expression for the inverse Laplace of this kind. @RonGordon